# How to get the AWS instance class attributes?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I know from an AWS API call (similar to `aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier instanceIdentifier`) that my AWS RDS Postgres instance has dbInstanceClass equal to "db.t2.large".

Using another API call, I want to get the attributes of a "db.t2.large" instance class especially the allocated memory.
I can get the value from the AWS documentation but I want the value programmatically.

What would be the API call or the equivalent on the command line?
An RDS instance is some kind of specialized EC2 instance but I did not find anything either under the EC2 API.

Thanks
Olivier

Answer (score 1):

From other people, I got the answer that there is no API for this. You have to rely on screen scraping...

Outside of the AWS documentation page, this web site http://www.ec2instances.info/rds gives the values for EC2 and RDS and you can download all the values or specific columns as a CSV file.